# Align height of all divs related to its content

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inside of a main div. I need to align all the divs heights equally. One div have more contents and another div have contents less than first div. But I need both divs height same.

```css
.align {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color : gray;
 margin-left : 5px;
 border : 1px solid #000;
 width : 100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "col-md-12">
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
```

here, the height is different. I need all divs height should same. when contents are added or deleted, height should be adjusted automatically for all divs. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are adding a column, don't forget to add a row.. To get equal height to every column, you have to add `display:flex;` to your row.. The change of code from your snippet is as follows..

```css
.align {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color : gray;
 margin-left : 5px;
 border : 1px solid #000;
 width : 100px;
 }
 .row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4 align">
      <p>hiiii</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 align">
      <p>hiiii</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hiiii</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hiiii</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 align">
      <p>hiiii</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for flexbox.

```
div.col-md-12{align-items: stretch; display: flex;}
```

[Link to Flexbox Parameters](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
I just used col-md-12 to demonstrate which div needs the flex property. Ideally you add a class, you don't want every col-md-12 column to have display flex.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches to this problem that work, some more involved than others. I'd definitely recommend checking out CSS-Tricks [comprehensive list of solutions](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) to this problem. Also, I'm not exactly sure what you want your final thing to look like, but you may want to switch from using inline-blocks to blocks and float left or right. You may not need to, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use flexBox as stated in other answers, or you can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` like so

keep in mind that display-flex might cause cross-browser problems

```css
.align {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color : gray;
 margin-left : 5px;
 border : 1px solid #000;
 width : 100px;
 display:table-cell;
 }
 .col-md-12 {
  display:table;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "col-md-12">
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-4 align">
    <p>hiiii</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is supported in every major browser. It is only a problem if you have to support browsers which have only a few percent market share. So if you can ignore these for your site flexbox is the way to go. Also see http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: as you can see there, IE10 and below do not support flexbox. which might be an issue that's why i said `might cause cross-browser problems` + other issues listed under the `Known Issues` tab .. I use flexbox myself. I just wanted to give a different solution in case it was needed